# Unhide All Users and Per User Radio Buttons for Non Admin User

Tags: windows-installer, installshield-2011

I have created an Installer in Installshield 2011. The Setup Type Dialog asks whether the Installation should be a PER USER or ALL USERS installation. 
When I login as non-admin, I can only install in PER USER Mode and that if fine. What I want is that when I run the Installation as a non-admin user, it should show the per user Install radio button as selected and All Users radio button as disabled.
However this is dependent on predefined constant DISABLE_ALLUSERBTN which is set to true and because of this both All User and Per User radio buttons are hidden.(invisible)
I want them to be visible, with Per User option selected by default and All Users radio button disabled. How can I do this?